# Represent a date with minimum possible character using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, date

I'm trying to represent a Date in symbolic format, and the goal is to do it with minimum characters with only integer or English Alphabets

What I tried is below SQL Server Query:

```
SELECT format(CAST(DATEDIFF(day, CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATE), CAST('2100-01-01' AS DATE)) AS INT), '00000')
```

This query give result `73049`, which is quite good to **represent** a date in **5** characters for as long as **two** centuries. With this I can very easily get the Date which it represent, making `'1900-01-01'` or some other date as fixed start date, as per my Application need.

I'm looking for possibility to reduce character length further.

Comment: And your dates range is...

Comment: Start Date '1900-01-01' and End Date '2100-01-01'- in my case.

Comment: By the way, you can achieve a significant reduction of you store the 5-digits number in its EXAEDECIMAL representation.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: If you want further reduction, you can invent a new set of "digits" going from 0-9,A-Z, but it would appear that you will need at least 4 chars.

Comment: Because the end result will be stored in a memory which really do not have much bytes, and each byte worth in this case

Comment: Thinking further, if you use upper and lower case chars, three chars would be more than enough (>200,000 different values). Of course, you will need to make two functions, one for packing and one for retrieving.

Comment: What is the range of most dates?

Comment: Just wondering, [`date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) stored in 3 bytes. [`smallint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) just 2 bytes, but may not able to cover your case. [`int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) take 4 bytes.  Is it worth to use custom format instead of `date`?

Comment: @Alex: It will be not saved in database, it will be saved in low memory chip storage, and I want to maximize the number of transaction stored, there are multiple Date values for different field, so even if I reduce one byte, there is too much benefit. Once read, the result will be interpreted by Application and displayed as proper date.

I'm trying to make is at least length to 4 for a date range of 200 years.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, maybe you can tell us how it stored.  So you can compare which solution is better: total days by int, total days by int in string, hex, character only, or even use whole byte (convert total days to "base 256" like ip address?).

Comment: Rather than focusing on individual dates, if your goal is to store a lot in not a lot of memory, using delta encoding on a range of dates and then storing the result as a variable-length integer may yield more savings (at the expensive of decoding time). Ditto other compression techniques. The actual question of how to represent a date with a *minimum* number of bits is very broad, as it depends entirely on your data and your access needs.